# cout.precision() equivalent for python

Tags: python, printing, floating-point, precision

In c++, there exists the cout.precision() to set the number of decimal digits I want to see when I print out a floating point number. Is there any equivalent solution in Python so that every time I want to print out a float I don't get those 11 extra digits that I don't actually need?

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can use the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) your floats explicitly:

```
print format(floatvalue, '.5f')
```

to output a float with 5 digits after the decimal. See the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) for details on the formatting options.

You can also use the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to control how a float value is interpolated into a larger string, using the same formatting parameters.